# Swift AVPlayer - The proper way to loop a video with custom rate

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

So I have an `AVPlayer` which I would like to continuously loop. This is not an issue as this works fine.

However, the user has the ability to edit the rate of the video. If the rate is changed, it will loop fine for 2-3 times and then the `AVPlayer` get stuck on the first frame.

The completion block is not called after it gets stuck.

Here is my code for looping the `AVPlayer`

```
// Loop video notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self = self, let player = self.player else { return }
        player.seek(to: .zero)
        player.play()
        player.rate = self.playerRate
    }
```